# Suggestions to turn an "accepted, pending revisions" into an "accepted"

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

As far as I understand "accepted pending revisions" is not the same as "submission accepted".

What are some important things to keep in mind while revising the submission in order for it to be finally accepted? Which have been the most useful to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they say that, they send you a list of suggested revisions (or several lists, one from each reviewer).  Just follow those suggestions.  When you send it back, explain which suggestions you followed, and which you did not (and why not).

Comment: What if the author decides to waive one or two of the referee's suggested revision? Won't he/she get mad at the author and retaliate suggesting a rejection in the end?

Comment: @Jamai-Con for a "typical" journal in a "typical" field (if such a thing could exist) accepted, pending revisions strongly implies that the editor believes the requested changes are so non-controversial and so minor that the author will have no reason not to follow them. In that case, it's likely the editor will sign off on them without going back to the reviewers. If the If the push back is strong on anything, then that might cause another round of review, comment, respond. Serious disagreement might lead to a trawl for another independent reviewer if the workflow allows.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks a lot for your answer. What would you say is a reasonable/typical lapse before the author receives a report on the revised version of the paper?

Answer (score 2):

Follow all suggestions that you agree with and document those you do not agree with and attach a clear explanation of why you disagree with them (possibly offering an alternative if you understand what exactly the referee was unhappy with in the original version or asking for clarification if you don't). Remember that it is *your* paper and you want to have it the way you think is right *more* than you want it to get published, so don't forget yourself when listing the parties whose opinion should be taken into account. Normally, a compromise satisfying everybody can be reached in finite time but it may require more than one iteration. As long as you stay polite and make your point of view clear and substantiated, occasional disagreements with reviewers and editors constitute a normal part of the publication process and are nothing to be afraid of. And, of course, try to meet the deadlines or at least inform the editors in advance when you cannot.

Comment: fedja (from mathlinks?): Thanks a lot for your answer. What would you say is a reasonable/typical lapse before the author receives a report on the revised version of the paper?

Answer (score 1):

Following all reviewers' suggestions and remaks (if appropriate).

Comment: And make sure that your changes are directly linked to reviewers comments and are noted in the cover letter back to the editor. Conflicts between reviewers recommendations should be noted and your response clarified.